# Qt connecttohost command showing connection refused from remote host

Tags: qt, qftp

I am running an application in WEC 7 and trying to connect to remote system, and I am using QFtp for transferring some data. When I try to connect to remote host using connecttohost, I am able to find the host but the connection is not successful and shows me error connectionrefused from remote host.

I tried the following things :

1. I made an exception in firewall for ftp connections so that remote host can accept the connections.
2. I turned on the discovery for the folders.
3. I added an inbound rule for port 21
4. I checked the option for ftp in control panel/Programs/program and features/turn on windows features/internet information services ,
   FTP server.

Comment: Can you connect with another ftp client from the same machine?

Comment: Hello Karsten, no it is unable to connect itself. I tried with 127.0.0.1 IP